# Regarding squaring the deviations when calculating the standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

I learned that the deviations are squared for a number of reasons.

(1) They make all values positive. Otherwise the sum of the deviation would be zero. But why not just take the absolute value of the deviations?

(2) To conserve the unit. If our data were units of meters then by squaring the deviations and then taking the square root the standard deviation has units of meters.

(3) My textbook says the following which I can't wrap my head around: "The sum of the squared deviations of any set of observations from their mean is the smallest that the sum of squared deviations from any number can possibly be. This is not true of the unsquared distances. So squared deviations point to the mean as center in a way that distances do not."

Can anyone explain this point in another way or a simpler way such that my little brain can understand please ? An example with data to supplement the explanation would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Let's find a point $\bar x$ such that it minimizes the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2$ over all observations $I$. First order condition (FOC):
$$\frac d {d\bar x}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2=2\bar x\sum_{i=1}^n(\bar x-x_i)=2\bar x(n\bar x-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)=0$$
$$\bar x=\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$

So, the mean is in fact the point that minimizes the sum of squared deviations.

Now, look at "unsquared distances" FOC:
$$\frac d {d\bar x}\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-\bar x|=
\sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm 2*1_{x_i<\bar x}-1=0$$

This is satisfied when $\bar x$ is the median, not the mean.

So, the passage is correct saying that mean and the variance are intimately linked, which shouldn't be surprising: these are first two moments of your distribution.